# Identify subsequent interaction done by the same id (redshift)

Tags: loops, case, amazon-redshift, transform, lag

I am trying to identify all agents that had an interaction with the same customer within 30 minutes, because they might feel bothered and shouldnt be called that frequently.

[image: table]

I'm not quite sure how to approach that, since case statements best work within a row. Maybe a loop would work iterating over rows (using redshift)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can use [LAG()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html) function to find the timestamp of the previous call.

Full answer:

```
WITH interactions AS (
    SELECT 
        agent, 
        customer, 
        call_time, 
        LAG(call_time) OVER (PARTITION BY agent, customer ORDER BY call_time) AS prev_call_time
    FROM 
        orders 
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    agent, 
    customer
FROM
    interactions
WHERE  
    DATEADD(MINUTE, prev_call_time, 30) >= call_time    
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I constructed the following statement: ```with order as ( select agent, customer, call_time from table order by 1,2,3) select order.*, case when agent=lag(agent,1) and customer=lag(customer,1) and datediff(minutes, call_time, lag(call_time,1) then 1 else 0 end as 'Double interaction' from order```